# How to add a button to an input field using AngularJS directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I need to write a directive that can would add a button to an input field and some other functionality.
So, ideally I want to have something like this

```
<input type="text" my-directive>
```

to end up being

```
<input type="text"><button ng-click="someAction()" ng-class="{'success': isSuccess()}" ng-disabled="isDisabled()">click me</button>
```

Simplified code for my directive:

```
 app.directive('myDirective', ['$q', '$timeout', function ($q, $timeout) {
                   return {
                    restrict: 'A',
                    template: '<button ng-click="someAction()" ng-class="{\'success\': isSuccess()}" ng-disabled="isDisabled()">click me</button>',

                    require: '?ngModel',
                    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

                        scope.isSuccess = function () {
                            ...
                        };

                        scope.isPending = function () {
                           ...
                        };
                        scope.someAction = function () {
                           ...
                        };


....}]);
```

The problem is that if I add this button in directive's template I end up with `<input><button></button></input>`

Creating a directive that would include also an input field is unfortunately not an option for me.
Please let me know if I need to provide more info.

Comment: Is there any issue with the `input` and the `button` element having a parent dummy element? I mean an element with directive like `<custom-input></custom-input>` can just insert the contents inside!

Comment: Unfortunately, the existing input fields all have different attributes and are used across the application, that's why I can not generate the same input field for all of them

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, I have found a solution.
You can add a the element by compiling it in your directive's link function and appending it to the element.

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                    var tpl = <button ng-click="someAction()" ng-class="{\'success\': isSuccess()}" ng-disabled="isDisabled()">click me</button>';
                    var el = $compile(tpl)(scope);
                    element.after(el);
...}
```